# Android onMenuItemClick receiving wrong item

Tags: java, android, xml, menu

I have this menu that pops up fine when I create it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/day"
        android:title="Day" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/week"
        android:title="Week" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:title="Month" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:title="Year" />
</menu>
```

For some reason, the `onMenuItemClick` is only giving me "Year" no matter which item I click on. This is a really strange problem and I have no idea why it's happening.

```
public void showMenu(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getContext(), v);
    MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.date_range_menu, popup.getMenu());
    popup.show();

    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.day:
                    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).toast("Day");
                    changeDateRange(DateRange.DAY);
                case R.id.week:
                    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).toast("Week");
                    changeDateRange(DateRange.WEEK);
                case R.id.month:
                    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).toast("Month");
                    changeDateRange(DateRange.MONTH);
                case R.id.year:
                    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).toast("Year");
                    changeDateRange(DateRange.YEAR);
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `break;` in each `case`.

Comment: Oh wow. Easy fix. I never use switch case syntax. Thanks!

Comment: You should revise Switch statement. You forgot break in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `break;` keyword to each case.